# How to separate long strings with variable number of spaces in between, in individual strings

Tags: python, string

I am trying to split strings, which are separated by a variable number of spaces.

something like this:

```
abcde          123456
```

I know how to trim a string, but I am having hard time here, because the 2 strings has a variable amount of spaces. If a string is long, it will have less spaces in between, so I can't find a way to delimit them clearly, so I can save each of them in a different string.

How do you actually do so?

Answer (score 2):

Use *.split()*:

```
input = 'abcde          123456'
output = input.split()
print(output)
```

> ['abcde', '123456']

Comment: why not just `input.split()` without any arguments?

Comment: @AnandSKumar "Explicit is better than implicit." =)

Comment: not when you are unneccessarily increasing amount of code. And who said its implicit? Its clearly defined in the documentation that `.split()` without argument would split based on all whitespaces - https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

Python [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)'s have a method called [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) just for this case.  When called on a string with no arguments, it will split on space and strip out any number of leading and trailing spaces:

```
data = 'abcde          123456'
letters, numbers = data.split()
```

Comment: Why do you need `strip()` if you are using `split()` without arguments, it would already have no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I agree with @AnandSKumar, I think you don't need `strip()` after using `split()`

Answer (score -1):

Its the best way to remove the spaces before splitting:

```
import re
my_string = "abcde          123456"
regex = re.compile(r'( [ ]+)')
shortend_string = regex.sub(' ', a)
elements = shortend_string.split(' ')
```

Comment: What is the advantage of regex + split, versus using directly strip?

Comment: @newbiez: There is no advantage. Just call `split` without any parameter and you're good to go.

Comment: regex is overhead here

Comment: The regex will handle all spaces with only one replacement.